# HSQL server mode while connection from DatabaseSwingManager throws exception java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException

Tags: database-connection, hsqldb

I have written a java code of connecting to server mode

```
p.setProperty("server.database.3", 
"file:G:/SERVERMODE/soamware;user=soamware;password=123@123");
p.setProperty("server.dbname.3", "soamware");
server.setProperties(p);
server.setLogWriter(null); // can use custom writer
server.setErrWriter(null); // can use custom writer
server.start();
try {
    //Registering the HSQLDB JDBC driver
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://ip/soamware; 
file:G:/SERVERMODE/soamware;user=soamware;password=123@123");
```

this code is working fine in netbeans with jdk8 and hsqldb2.5.1, however the console shows the build is not terminated and its still running. While when i connect to SwingDatabaseManager

[image]
with same url, username and password as mentioned in java code. It throws above mentioned exception. Kindly clarify also, why my program doesnt exit. I am not adding "server.shutdownCatalogs(1);" statement at end because then I cannot perform multiple operations in one session.

Comment: Your program doesn't exit because the server you started is still running. Your image of the DatabaseManagerSwing is incomplete and doesn't show the URL or the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are starting the server with only one database, you should set `database.0` properties. You shouldn't use the `@` character at all on a connection string because it has a special meaning. You shouldn't use the file path when connecting to a server database. Use the `dbname.0` value only. Edited code below:

```
p.setProperty("server.database.0", "file:G:/SERVERMODE/soamware;user=soamware;password=123x123");

p.setProperty("server.dbname.0", "soamware");
server.setProperties(p);
server.setLogWriter(null); // can use custom writer
server.setErrWriter(null); // can use custom writer
server.start();
try {
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
    con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/soamware", "soamware", "123x123");
```